# VimScripting NERDTree

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

Trying to force cursor to leave NERDTree window on MacVim startup (`mvim .`) so I could continue make new split-ups and open certain files in them. But it feels like cursor is stuck in the NERDTree and doesn't listen to me.
Here's contents of my `.vimrc.local`:

```
function! SplitIt()
  vsplit " this works
  exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>" " doesn't. also tried normal ^W^W, bd etc.
  " vsplit Gemfile
  " ...
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call SplitIt()
```

Tried a whole buncha commands which works well when I type them in NERDTree window, but are useless in this script. Driving me crazy.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use NERDTree and this works. It switches from NERDTree window to the file I want to edit, and splits (or whatever you want to do):

```
function! SplitIt()
    exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>"
    vsplit
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call SplitIt()
```

---

Other possibility is beginning with it disabled and enable it with <kbd>F2</kbd> or any other key:

Comment the line that enables it at the beginning:

```
""" autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

And add a map to enable it easily:

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Comment: I've updated Janus to January 2012 release and put the script into `~/.vimrc.after` *now* this works. https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/wiki/Customization Thanks for help.